# Batch program to copy files from one folder to another folder

Tags: command-line

This is what I am trying to achieve.

- I have two folders `SRC` and `DESTINATION`. `SRC` contains several subdirectories and files in it.
- A batch file should be built upon clicking it the following should be done

  1. Delete all contents from `DESTINATION` folder
  2. Copies all the files/subdirectories from `SRC` to `DESTINATION`

Can someone help me with this ?.

If this activity requires significant effort (I don’t know whether the above is simple to implement or not), do point me some resources for me to dig into it.

Comment: This is not Ubuntu specific. Additionally: how sohuld the (bash-) script know the SRC and DEST parameters without providing them manually? The two functions you are looking for are `rm -rf` and `cp -r`. Read their man pages, if you are unsure about what they do.

Comment: rsync may be something to look into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the following file using your favorite (plain) text editor (e.g. `gedit` or `kwrite`)

```
#!/bin/bash

source_dir=SRC
dest_dir=DESTINATION

rm -rf "$dest_dir/*" #Remove the contents of DESTINATION
cp -r "$source_dir/* $dest_dir/" #Copy the contents of SRC into DESTINATION
```

The above should be saved with a meaningful name; e.g. `copy_SRC_to_DESTINATION.sh` and made executable with

```
chmod +x /path/to/copy_SRC_to_DESTINATION.sh
```

from a terminal

Now, in your file manager, navigate to where you saved the file, double-click on it and choose "Run".

**Notes**

- As onse commented, you should edit the script file and manually enter the actual names of your directories instead of `SRC` and `DESTINATION` in the above listing.
- Replace `/path/to/` in the `chmod` line above with the actual path where you saved the script file.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't just use `cp` and `rm`?

`cp -R` will copy all files and folders from selected location to other and `rm -R` will remove all files and folders from selected location.

```
cp -R <sourde> <destination>
rm -R <directory to remove>
```

Tou may also use `rmdir` for removing directories.

I think this two simple steps don't need to write a executable file for it.